# IF statement checking null variable to use min

Tags: php

This seems pretty simple, but I can't figure that out.

I am checking  a few variables before showing some stuff on the screen, and I have a variable which can be null at some point.

On my if statement I have:

```
if ($a != 'abc' && ($a == $b || $b == $c) && min($variable) > 3) { ... }
```

How can I set it true if min($variable) is null, if all the other statements are true?

Comment: Use an OR like you do in the section right before that.

Comment: I am pretty sure that things like `$1` and `$2` are _not_ valid php variable names.

Comment: that's just an example.. they are not the real names..

Comment: Then please modify the example such that at least the code is syntactically correct. Other users finding this later on will get confused for nothing. A minimal example should at least be executable and syntactically correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be using a ternary operator  inside  ( )

```
if ($1 != 'abc' && ($1 == $2 || $2 == $3) && 
   ( $variable ==  null ? true : min($variable) > 3)  ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your question,

the `min($variable)` maybe null and you want to check it whether it's value less than 3 or null value ?

```
if ($a != 'abc' && ($a == $b || $b == $c) 
    && (min($variable) > 3 || min($variable) == null)) { ... }
```